# Pyparsing 1.4 TypeError: len() of unsized object

Tags: python, pyparsing

I've got this parser that is working for the newer pyparsing, but now it's throwing an error with an older version...`Pyparsing 1.4-1.1` to be exact. I have stepped through with debugging and can't figure out how to fix this. Can anyone tell me what is the issue here. Thanks!

```
pairs = [{'category': 'General Information',
      'kv': Group(Word(alphanums) + Word(alphanums))},
     {'category': 'Last Reset:',
      'kv': Group(Word(alphas, max=1) + Word(alphas)) + Literal(':').suppress()
            + Group(Regex(date_regex) + Regex(time_regex)
            + Optional(SkipTo(LineEnd())))
      }
     ]
```

the full traceback is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foobar.py", line 33, in ?
    pairs = [{'category': 'General Information',
  File "/var/lib/python-support/python2.4/pyparsing.py", line 1219, in __init__
    if len(pattern) == 0:
TypeError: len() of unsized object
```

Comment: `Group(Regex(date_regex) + Regex(time_regex)` - is the `Group` meant to be unclosed? It's including the `Optional` on the next line.

Comment: Try building up the `pairs` data structure in separate steps to get a more informative traceback.

Comment: @user2357112 I tried to and deconstructing this, I see that something in my second pair is an issue. Can't find what it is though. It works fine in on my Mac with `Python 2.7.2` and `Pyparsing 2.0.1` but in VMWare with `Pyparsing 1.4` and `Python 2.4` and I can't upgrade this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pyparsing is a very small-footprint library, just a single source file. If you can't install a new version, just add the proper version of pyparsing in with your application's own source code. Of course, this is not ideal, you now have to maintain the pyparsing lib code in with your own app. But it sounds like you are in kind of a desperate spot.